# How can I adjust the frame for this camera app on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera

So I'm trying to create my own custom camera view for my app. I've found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) and have basically used it as my source code. The camera functions seem fine but the view frame turns out to have been "centred".

I have looked into the demo code to find out where I can adjust the frame size of the camera view but could not find anything. Does anyone know how I can adjust the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which you referred uses storyboards to set the frame, you can change the frame of the camera view there .see the below image for reference

[image]

also delete the constranits to set the frame correctly. see the below image for reference.

[image]